# Strange C Array Behavior with qemu

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, qemu

I'm working on making a kernel for a simple system operating and I'm stuck at a strange behavior with a `char` array in C. I'm using qemu as an emulator, OS is compiled as x86_64.
Given the following code:

```
char msg[] = "Hello World!";
int i = 0;
while (msg[i] != 0)
    i++;
byte *mem = (byte*)VIDEO_ADDRESS; //VGA text mode
*mem = '0' + i; //print '<'
```

The number printed on screen is 0 even though it should print `'<' ('0' + 12)`.
As a test I tried printing the first character in the array and it works if I use a hard-coded index:

```
*mem = msg[0]; //'H' is printed
```

Strangely enough, the following doesn't work:

```
int i = 0;
*mem = msg[i]; //no output (or null character)
```

The following works as well:

```
*mem = 'H';
```

Comment: And what happens with `*men = 60`? Does it print `<`?

Comment: That is *very* weird. Based *just* on what you've stated, it almost looks like it's the use of `i` (or some local var) that's causing an issue. Since it's an OS, you may want to look into whether the stack segments/selectors have been set up correctly. You could also find the smallest complete program that exhibits the problem and have a look (and post it here) at the assembler code for it.

Comment: @Pablo Yes, `*mem = 60` works just fine. I'll look into the assembler code and update with an answer as soon as I can.

Comment: what, exactly, is the value of VIDEO_ADDRESS?

Comment: is your video card in VGA text mode?

Comment: regarding: `while (msg[i] != 0)`  the compiler is performing an implicit conversion between int 0 (0x00000000) and char 0 (0x00).  Your compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: regarding: `*mem = '0' + i;`  your compiler should have warned you about the conversion from `int` to `byte` . Suggest: `*mem = (byte)('0' + i);`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to declare mem as `volatile byte *`.

The code snippets you've written look to the compiler like nothing happens to *mem after you write to it.  If nobody ever makes use of *mem, then the compiler can optimize out instructions that write there, but it's not required to.

`volatile` is created for this type of situation, where something else (the video display system) is reading or writing memory that the compiler doesn't know about.

You can read more about `volatile` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile